# Is there a way to retopo a model that is already rigged and textured without losing said rig and texture?

Tags: uv, retopology

So, weird question I guess, but I have this model that is fully textured and rigged, but the topology is a mess. (it's a ripped game asset, not sure if... that's allowed...) Is there any way for me to retopo the model, but make it so that the new geometry's outline sits perfectly on top of the old one on the UV maps?

If I just merge/change the topology of the original mesh, the textures get messed up, and I'm not 100% sure how to fix them, or if that's even the best way to go about it.
[image: for example, this is what the mesh looks at first]
[image: and this is what happens when I alt+J (tris to quads)]

I'm not sure if there's any way around this, but any ideas are welcome! Thanks!

And would it be a matter of just parenting the new topology to the correct bones when it comes to the rigging part?

Comment: you can create a new object that will be the rotopologized version of the current object, and bake the texture. For the rigging it will be lost, you'll need to parent the new object to the armature and maybe give some corrections in Weight Paint mode

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to try:  use the transfer attributes modifier to project the vertex groups from the bad skinned mesh to the new clean mesh, just so long as they are very close to each other it can work. Results may vary.

here's a tutorial on the topic.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j823wSrHJnA